# Integration with respect to the Dirac measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $X$ be a non-empty set, $a \in X$ and $\delta_a$ be the Dirac measure:

$$\delta_a(A)= \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if $a \in A$}\\ 0 &\text{if $a \notin A$}\\ \end{cases}$$

Consider the measure space  $(X, \mathscr{P}(X), \delta_a)$

$$\mathcal{L}^1(X, \delta_a) = \left\{ f : X \to \overline{\mathbb{R}} : \text{$f$ is $\delta_a$-measurable and $\int_X |f|\,\mathrm{d}\delta_a < \infty$}  \right\}$$

Let's say I want to determine the above set explicitly. Since $\int_X |f| \,\mathrm{d}\delta_a =  |f(a)|$, does it mean that $\mathcal{L}^1(X, \delta_a)$ is simply the space of functions that don't take infinite values at $a$ ?

Comment: yes, it is what that means

Comment: Yes, but moreover you must mod out by functions of measure $0$, which is most functions really. In fact, $L^1(X,\delta_a) \cong \mathbb{R}$ as Hilbert spaces.